# How to store the recursive value in my map in dynamic programing

Tags: c++, c++11, dynamic-programming

I m trying to find the number of ways you can get from the top-left grid to the bottom right grid using dynamic programing so I m using `map<pair<int, int>, int>` for memoization.

When I try to insert the k value in the map it doesn't get stored in my map, only my `c` and `r` integers get stored. Why is this happening?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
#include <algorithm>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <map>
using namespace std;
int grid(int r , int c , map<pair<int,int> ,int>& m1);
int main()
{
    map<pair<int ,int>,int> m1;
    int k=grid(2,3 ,m1);
    cout<<k<<endl;
    for(auto& it1:m1){
        cout<<it1.first.first<<"\t"<<it1.first.second<<"\t"<<it1.second<<endl;
    }
}

int grid(int r , int c , map<pair<int,int> ,int>& m1)
{
    if(r==0 || c==0) return 0;
    if(r==1 && c==1) return 1;
    if(m1[{r,c}]!=NULL){return m1[{r,c}];}
    int k=grid(r-1,c,m1)+grid(r,c-1,m1);
    m1.insert({{r,c},k});
    cout<<"k:"<<k<<endl;
    return grid(r-1,c,m1)+grid(r,c-1,m1);
}
```

Output:-----------------------------------

```
k:1
k:1
k:1
k:1
k:1
k:2
k:1
k:1
k:3
k:1
k:1
k:1
k:1
k:1
k:2
k:1
k:1
3
1       2       0
1       3       0
2       1       0
2       2       0
2       3       0
```

Comment: See [Why should I not #include <bits/stdc++.h>?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31816095/3422102) and [Why is “using namespace std;” considered bad practice?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1452721/364696)

Comment: Should also change to `if (m1.find({r,c}) != m1.end()) { return m1[{r,c}]; }` to properly test is the key `{r,c}` already exists instead of using `NULL`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way you check for a value in the map with `m1[{r,c}]` will create the entry if it does not exist. When you try to add the key later with `m1.insert`, the value will not be added because the key already exists.

You can either replace the insert with

```
m1[{r,c}] = k;
```

or use `find` or `lower_bound` to check if the key exists. This also has the advantage of not doing multiple lookups for the same key.

```
auto it = m1.lower_bound({r,c});
if (it != m1.end) return it->second;  // key found, return value
int k = ...;
m1.insert(it, {{r,c}, v});
```

Using the hint version of [`insert`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/insert) takes advantage of the previous unsuccessful lookup to avoid traversing the map to locate the correct place to insert it.